# How do we know that we can trust proof assistance to produce correct results?

Tags: proof-assistant

Well, pretty simple question, how do we know that we can trust the proof assistants? I ask this question as a complete lay in proof assistants. Maybe a trivial answer could be "because smart people designed it too", but couldn't there be code errors, or some manifestation  of Goedel's incompleteness theorem in the proof assistant itself?

Comment: Note that Gödel's incompleteness is not a paradox, it's just a theorem like any other theorem in mathematics.

Comment: See [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18421/how-do-they-verify-a-verifier-of-formalized-proofs) and the plethora of answers.

Answer (score 3):

The **completeness** in Gödel's completeness theorem (yes there is one), is the property that you can prove everything that *ought to be* provable. Of course there is a precise definition of these. Dually, there is a property called **soundness**, that says everything that shouldn't be provable indeed can't. The **completeness** in Gödel's *in*completeness theorem is a related but different thing. It says that for every proposition, either it or its negation is provable. This can also be seen as requiring things that *ought to* be provable.

Now if you want to trust anything a proof assistant verifies, you are only concerned about soundness. Completeness has nothing to do here: A system can be impotent in that it doesn't prove a lot of things, but this doesn't mean it is not trustworthy.

---

Now back to the main question. Note that we don't have to build a perfect proof assistant: it just has to be better than its competitors (humans) for us to shift our trust to it. There are a few sources of errors to consider:

- The foundational theories behind proof assistants. Basically if the rules are wrong, then following them isn't exactly the best way to produce correct results. This is studied in logic, programming language theory, and other related fields.
- The code that implements these rules. This source of error can be reduced by (1) keeping the rules simple and codebase small, so it is easier to catch bugs; and (2) let multiple people independently write the code in different ways, so even if there are errors, it is less likely that these people make the same mistakes.
- The code that communicate between the core code above and humans. Usually it is extremely tedious to directly interact with the core code because of its simplicity. It will ask for the tiniest details even though it has asked for them previously, thousands of times. We need to make sure there is no miscommunication. For example if we wanted to prove Fermat's last theorem, but what the core actually checked is a trivial theorem which only looks like FLT, then it will unknowingly give us the pass.
- We also need to make sure the computer is executing the code correctly.

Making sure code work properly is a well-studied field because the military and medical services etc are already interested in it. (You don't want nuclear weapons or surgery robots to end up somewhere wrong!) Proof assistants can leverage existing research.

- Finally, there are things that can't be checked by a machine. If you define the even numbers to be those divisible by 3, then as far as the machine can tell there's nothing wrong. It's just a particularly weird name, and nothing in mathematics says we can't have weird names. So the proof assistant would be entirely correct when it says that 9 is an even number, because it is true using the definition we gave.

I'll add some examples when I'm at the computer.

Comment: The last observation is very important. It is up to the individual working within a sound system to make sure definitions have the meaning you want them to. The assignment of "even" and "odd" goes back to the Greeks in reference to the difference between male and female bodies. The choice for 1 to be "odd" was only inspired by their patriarchal society. In other words, it was complete arbitrary nonsense coupled with a human desire for binary assignments (on/off, this/that, odd/even, etc.). Weird names are okay, so long as the core concept remains true to what you intend.

Comment: Gödel's completeness theorem is for First Order Logic; which is not used in most of the proof assistants commonly used today.